# What did Courtney mean by this realization?

Tags: stargirl

In *Stargirl* season 2, episode 2, near the episode's climax, with the Green Lantern lantern damaged, Courtney suddenly comes to a realization about Jennie and how she can resolve the problem:

> Jennie *is* the lantern, so she can absorb its energy so it won't explode.

But... what exactly does that statement mean?  it seems absurd and contradictory on the face of it:

> how can she be the same as a distinct object she is holding in her hands, which object existed before she was born?

I've heard more than once that *Stargirl* does a better job remaining true to its source material than most modern comic adaptations, but I've never read any of the relevant comics.  I've also heard that Jennie's character is based on one of the more unusual Green Lantern incarnations.  Is there anything relevant that explains what this line means, or do we just have to wait and see?